# How fix compile error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::__1::string&

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I'm new in C++ and i can't figure out what's wrong with this code

```
 string& GetAddonCmeterString(string& sid) {
     ostringstream oss;
     oss <<  "{"; 
     oss <<     "currentValues : {sid : " << sid << "}"; 
     oss <<  "}";
     string& result = oss.str();
     return result;
 }
```

Compile error message:

error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::__1::string& {aka std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >&}' from an rvalue of type 'std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >'
      string& result = oss.str();

Comment: Use `string` instead of `string&` on that line

Comment: That's the least of your worries. You're returning a reference to a local variable.

Comment: Also, you're not modifying `sid` so you should pass by `const` reference.

Answer (score 2):

compiles or not,
***Do not return pointer or referene to a local variable!***

`result` will be destructed and de-allocated when `GetAddonCmeterString`is finished, you are returning a memory address of an object that does not exist anymore!

you should return the string by value*:

```
  string GetAddonCmeterString(string& sid) {
     ostringstream oss;
     oss <<  "{"; 
     oss <<     "currentValues : {sid : " << sid << "}"; 
     oss <<  "}";
     return oss.str();
 }
```

*the string will not be returned by value, but will be `moved`, but because you are new to C++ let's keep it simple for the sake of discussion.

Comment: So, if i rewrite last line like this: return new string(oss.str());

Comment: then you will have to return the string as a pointer or reference, and track it down until you don't need it anymore. then you will have to call `delete`. so much headache for something you can return by value.

Comment: I know it David Haim, the main question was about compile error

Comment: yes if you return it as `*new std::string(oss.str());` but this is highly not recomended from the reasons I stated above. do not do that.

Comment: I still has this compile error and is no matter what it returns from stack memory or from heap

Comment: you didn't compile it with the code I provided you.